# Foreign key reference to a new schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to move some tables to a new schema. When I moved it, I am getting errors at the foreign key referencing. I also tried giving permissions. Accounts is the old schema where address table lived and I moved the address to a new schema called address. I get the error table or view does not exists:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS.PARTY_ADDRESS
(
 PARTY_ID NUMBER(18,0),
 ADDRESS_ID NUMBER(18,0),
 CONSTRAINT PARTY_ADDRESS_PK PRIMARY KEY (PARTY_ID, ADDRESS_ID),
 constraint PARTY_ADDRESS_party_fk foreign key (PARTY_ID)
 references PARTY(id),
 constraint PARTY_ADDRESS_ADDRESS_UNQ unique (ADDRESS_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTS.PARTY_ADDRESS ADD CONSTRAINT PARTY_ADDRESS_address_fk FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS.ADDRESS(id);
```

I have also given grant in address:

```
GRANT ALL ON ADDRESS.ADDRESS TO ACCOUNTS;
```

Comment: I think you need to drop the constraints and re-create them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry I did not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: I'm never keen on multi-schema designs, as they complicate development, maintenance, support and deployment for often only minor benefits. Generally when you do have multiple schemas, it is best to minimise dependencies between them. I don't think I have seen a cross-schema foreign key in any system I have ever worked on.

Answer (score 1):

The table privilege `REFERENCES` is required for a schema to be able to create referential constraints to a table in another schema. `GRANT ALL` should have worked. In my test case it did work, e.g.:

Schema 1:

```
create table schema1.t1 (id number primary key);

Table T1 created.
```

Schema 2:

```
create table schema2.t2 (id number primary key, fk number);

Table T2 created.

alter table schema2.t2 add constraint fktest
  foreign key (fk) references schema1.t1 (id);

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Schema 1:

```
grant references on schema1.t1 to schema2;

Grant succeeded.
```

Schema 2:

```
alter table schema2.t2 add constraint fktest
  foreign key (fk) references schema1.t1 (id);

Table T2 altered.
```

Schema 1:

```
revoke references on schema1.t1 from schema2;

ORA-01981: CASCADE CONSTRAINTS must be specified to perform this revoke

revoke references on schema1.t1 from schema2 cascade constraints;

Revoke succeeded.
```

It also works if you `GRANT ALL`:

Schema 1:

```
grant all on schema1.t1 to schema2;

Grant succeeded.
```

Schema 2:

```
alter table schema2.t2 add constraint fktest
  foreign key (fk) references schema1.t1 (id);

Table T2 altered.
```